# Как правильно написать код чтобы создать пустой адаптер?

Tags: java, android, listview, mvc, adapter

Это мой код в Adaptere

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (modelAlbums!=null){
        return modelAlbums.results.albummatches.album.size();
    }else {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Это код ошибки. Так как Модель пустая то получается такая ошибка.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.eranewgames.baseandroidproject.models.ModelAlbums$ResultsBean$AlbummatchesBean com.eranewgames.baseandroidproject.models.ModelAlbums$ResultsBean.albummatches' on a null object reference
```

МОЯ МОДЕЛЬ

```
public class ModelAlbums {


@SerializedName("results") public ResultsBean results;

public static class ResultsBean {
    @SerializedName("opensearch:Query") public OpensearchQueryBean opensearchQuery;
    @SerializedName("opensearch:totalResults") public String opensearchtotalResults;
    @SerializedName("opensearch:startIndex") public String opensearchstartIndex;
    @SerializedName("opensearch:itemsPerPage") public String opensearchitemsPerPage;
    @SerializedName("albummatches") public AlbummatchesBean albummatches;
    @SerializedName("@attr") public attrBean attr;

    public static class OpensearchQueryBean {
        @SerializedName("#text") public String text;
        @SerializedName("role") public String role;
        @SerializedName("searchTerms") public String searchTerms;
        @SerializedName("startPage") public String startPage;
    }

    public static class AlbummatchesBean {
        @SerializedName("album") public List<AlbumBean> album;

        public static class AlbumBean {
            @SerializedName("name") public String name;
            @SerializedName("artist") public String artist;
            @SerializedName("url") public String url;
            @SerializedName("streamable") public String streamable;
            @SerializedName("mbid") public String mbid;
            @SerializedName("image") public List<ImageBean> image;

            public static class ImageBean {
                @SerializedName("#text") public String text;
                @SerializedName("size") public String size;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class attrBean {
        @SerializedName("for") public String forX;
    }
}
```

}

Почему ModelAlbums не null?

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Незнаю правильно ли я делаю или нет. Но чтобы каждый раз не создавать новый Adapter я создаю вначале Adapter пустой. А затем обновляю его через notifyDataSet.

Все бы ничего да вот с Моделью это не прокатывает. А делать целый список Ifof на проверку modelAlbums modelAlbums.results ит.д. это просто ужасно будет. Гавнокод получится.

Есть предложения? от профи))

Comment: Вообще никаких идей нет чтоли? Блин я думал уже кто - то столкнулся с такой проблемой =((

Comment: Так какая именно у вас проблема? Передавайте в адаптер не всю модель, а только список `List<AlbumBean> album`.